# Excel VBA Shapes TextFrame Characters Text Charset

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

I insert textbox to my Excel 2013 document and put some text

> 正体字/繁体字

with UTF-8 symbols
In textbox its looks ok but when I trying to msgbox it with command

```
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text
```

I get something like

> ???/???

So how to set UTF_8 charset to get normally this text in msgbox or into variable?

Comment: As far as I know, MsgBox won't work with non ASCII characters.

Comment: Msgbox is bound to Americanism

Comment: How are you testing the variables? Immediate/Watch/Locals windows won't work either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [display non-English language text in a message box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013443/display-non-english-language-text-in-a-message-box)

Comment: Or duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910166/foreign-characters-show-up-as-in-vba-2003-how-to-set-up-utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create something that **looks** like a MsgBox and **functions** like a MsgBox, but can better handle UniCode:

```
Public Declare Function MessageBoxU Lib "user32" Alias "MessageBoxW" _
                            (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                             ByVal lpText As Long, _
                             ByVal lpCaption As Long, _
                             ByVal wType As Long) As Long
Sub MsgBoxSubstitute()
    Dim s As String
    s = ChrW(8451)
    MessageBoxU 0, StrPtr(s), StrPtr("MsgBox Substitute"), 0
End Sub
```

Using the *Windows API.*  Note it has a nice built-in mechanism to dismiss the message.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround is to create a form and display your message in a label. I think labels are UTF-8 enabled.